# When i post a long running Runnable to the main thread why isn't it blocked for that time?

Tags: android, multithreading

If i post a `Runnable` with `Thread.sleep(10000)` command, why is the system behaving normally if the UI Thread can only execute one message at a time?

I made this thread in the main activity. Button clicks are processed by the main thread from the `MessageQueue`, then if the runnable in `h.post()` is currently active on the main thread then how are the button clicks being processed? shouldn't they wait in the `MessageQueue`?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for(int ii=0;ii<9;ii++){
                    i++;
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        h.post(new Runnable(){

                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    t();
                                    // TODO: Implement this method
                                }
                            });
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {}
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: post your entire code

Comment: I think this link can help us: http://electrozoic.com/asynctasks-runnables-handlers-and-threads-oh-my/

it depends on how we do run the Runnable

Answer (score 0):

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       Thread.sleep(10000); 
       //the thread stoped/sleeped is the thread of Runnable belongs to, 
       //but not the Main UI thread
    }
};
```

**Not block Main UI thred is exactly what Runnable want to achieve**.

Comment: The `Runnable` inside `Handler.post()` is run on the main thread. I'm saying that if this `Runnable` instructs the main thread to sleep, then why is it not.

Answer (score 0):

Aw that was a very trivial question. The inner `Runnable` is on the main thread while the outer one is time consuming. So the inner `Runnable` won't block the UI Thread. Thanks!